# Angular directive test not passing, but works in browser. Suspecting jqlite to be the culprit

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to test an Angular directive, and I'm not sure why my tests aren't passing. I'd really appreciate a few extra sets of eyes to help me get this figured out.

The directive under test is a validation directive that will validate whether or not the element's value matches the element with the id passed in via attribute:

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('mustMatch', ->
    restrict: 'A'
    require: 'ngModel'
    link: (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) ->
      # I've tried both of these, traversal vs selection, neither work under test
      #matchedElement = element.parents('form').find attrs.mustMatch
      matchedElement = $(attrs.mustMatch)

      ctrl.$parsers.unshift (val) ->
        if val is matchedElement.val()
          ctrl.$setValidity 'mustMatch', true
          return val
        else
          ctrl.$setValidity 'mustMatch', false
          return undefined
  )
```

Here's my testing setup:

```
describe 'Directive: mustMatch', ->
  scope = null
  element = null
  form = null

  beforeEach module 'app'

  beforeEach inject ($compile, $rootScope) ->
    scope = $rootScope.$new()
    scope.model = text1: '', text2: ''
    element = angular.element '''<form name="someForm">
        <input type="text" name="text1" ng-model="model.text1" id="text1"/>
        <input type="text" name="text2" ng-model="model.text2" must-match="#text1"/>
      </form>'''
    $compile(element)(scope)
    scope.$digest()
    form = scope.someForm

  it 'should fail validation if values do not match', ->
    form.text1.$setViewValue 'some text'
    form.text2.$setViewValue 'some other text'
    expect(scope.model.text2).toBe undefined
    expect(form.text2.$valid).toBe false

  # TODO: Why isn't this passing? Is the matched element not being found?
  it 'should pass validation if values match', ->
    value = 'some text'
    form.text1.$setViewValue value
    form.text2.$setViewValue value
    expect(scope.model.text2).toBe value
    expect(form.text2.$valid).toBe true
```

The first test passes just fine, but the second is returning `undefined`/`false`, failing the expectations of the test. **Again, the directive works just fine in the browser, but that second unit test is giving me issues.**

I do have jQuery in my `karma.conf.js` file as my app has dependency on Bootstrap and a few other jQuery plugins. I have other directive tests that use this same approach. My theory is that the element selection in the directive isn't working properly under test. Am I barking up the right tree? Is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

*Update*

Still running into the issue, but I believe I've isolated the problem to the DOM traversal I'm doing to get the matching element. If I replace this line of the directive's linking function...

```
if val is matchedElement.val()
```

... with this line ...

```
if val is 'some text'
```

I can get the test to pass. So that tells me that the value of the link function's `element` argument is probably not what I'm expecting it to be while under test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting several hours ripping my hair out and trying different fixes, I stumbled upon the answer to my question. My problem was in the `beforeEach` function. **I didn't set `model.text1` to the value I was expecting to validate against.** Here's my updated test:

```
describe 'Directive: mustMatch', ->
  scope = null
  element = null
  form = null

  beforeEach module 'app'

  beforeEach inject ($compile, $rootScope) ->
    scope = $rootScope.$new()

    # Setting `model.text1` to 'some text' fixed my problem
    scope.model = text1: 'some text', text2: ''

    element = angular.element '''<form name="someForm">
        <input type="text" name="text1" ng-model="model.text1" id="text1" />
        <input type="text" name="text2" ng-model="model.text2" id="text2" must-match="#text1" />
      </form>'''
    $compile(element)(scope)
    scope.$digest()
    form = scope.someForm
    form.text1.$setViewValue 'some text'

  it 'should fail validation if values do not match', ->
    form.text2.$setViewValue 'some other text'
    expect(scope.model.text2).toBe undefined
    expect(form.text2.$valid).toBe false

  it 'should pass validation if values match', ->
    form.text2.$setViewValue 'some text'
    expect(scope.model.text2).toBe 'some text'
    expect(form.text2.$valid).toBe true
```